# Prove that if $f$ is measurable, then $f(Tx)$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

### Definition of measurability of function

$f$ is said to be measurable if $\{x:f(x)>a\}$ is measurable.

---

Prove that, for $f$ defined and measurable in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f(Tx)$ is measurable, where $T$ is a nonsingular linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

1. Let $E_1=\{x:f(x)\gt{}a\}$ and let $E_2=\{x:f(Tx)\gt{}a\}$.
2. Then $E_1$ is measurable. If $E_2$ is measurable, then $f(Tx)$ is measurable.
3. $T^{-1}E=\{T^{-1}x:f(x)\gt{}a\}=\{T^{-1}x:f(TT^{-1}x)\gt{}a\}=\{y:f(Ty)\gt{}a\}=E_2$
4. Since the inverse image of a measurable set is measurable under the linear transformations, $f(Tx)=E_2$ is mesurable.

I don't understand process #4. What does it mean? Is it mean that $T^{-1}E$ is measurable? Why??

Comment: All linear transformations $T:\Bbb{R}^m\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ are continuous, hence measurable.

Comment: @sqtrat Is it fine if I do not contain the proof of that?

Comment: Well, it really depends on what you have done in say class? Do you know that all Borel measurable functions are continuous and similarly do you know that  linear transformations are continuous?

Comment: @sqtrat measurability is not enough (it means that preimage of open sets is measurable). Linearity has this special property that preimage of measurable is measurable (which is not true in general for continuous functions).

Comment: Oh yes, sorry Borel measurable functions are continuous not the other way around.

Comment: @Crostul What does it mean that preimage of measurable is measurable? does it mean that since $T$ is measurable, preimage of $T$ (i.e. $T^{-1}$) is also measurable? If so, how can I assure that $T$ is measurable?

Comment: @Crostul Your comment about linear functions is very interesting. So it's obvious that if $T: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is linear, then the preimage of a Lebesgue measurable set is Lebesgue measurable. But is it true for linear transformations between different spaces, $T:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$?